# Vim vertical resize shortcut

Tags: vim

I would like to set a shortcut to resize the width of two panes:

```
:vertical resize +2
```

I would like to map this to `[option]` `+` (in other words, shift + option + "+). I am on a mac. I tried doing the following. How would I add in this shortcut for a `nnoremap` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this without having to switch to the ex command line:

To change vertical height:

```
[n] --> ctrl + w --> [+ | -]
```

And horizontal:

```
[n] --> ctrl + w --> [< | >]
```

Comment: I am making the assumption that you're mostly just annoyed at the number of keystrokes it takes to do it with `:vertical resize`

Comment: thanks for this. That just seems to place me into the adjacent window: I haven't been able to get that to work but maybe I'm entering in the wrong keystrokes. I'm trying, for example `[ctrl]` `w` `+`

Comment: oh I see, I forgot the shift on the +-><. Works like a charm, thanks

Comment: i forget the shift a lot too